# Compare DateTimeOffset with daylight saving time

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

Here the DateTimeOffset instances represent the same time, but one instance has DST and other doesn't.
I would like to compare instances without DST, so the result would be True.

```
using System;

var today = DateTime.Today;

// Today YYYY-MM-01
var firstDayMonth = new DateTimeOffset(
    new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, today.Kind).AddHours(12));

// Add year offset from 2000
DateTimeOffset withYearOffset = firstDayMonth.AddYears(2000 - firstDayMonth.Year);

// Add month offset from 1
var withMonthOffset = withYearOffset.AddMonths(1 - withYearOffset.Month);

// Add day offset from 1
var calculated_dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0 = withMonthOffset.AddDays(1 - withMonthOffset.Day);

// 01.01.2000 12:00:00 +03:00
Console.WriteLine(calculated_dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0);

var dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0 = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddHours(12));

// 01.01.2000 12:00:00 + 02:00
Console.WriteLine(dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0);

// False
Console.WriteLine(calculated_dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0.Equals(dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0));
```

Comment: You'll probably need to do something with `TimeZoneInfo`.

Comment: "one instance has DST and other doesn't" - but it's more baked in than *just* a DST difference. You've computed midday when DST is in effect and you've also computed a midday when DST isn't in effect. Literally, those times are *not the same time*.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to UTC solves the problem.

```
var calculated_dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0 = withMonthOffset.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(firstDayMonth.Offset.Hours);


var dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0_withOffset = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddHours(12));
var dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0 = dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0_withOffset.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(dt_2000_1_1_12_0_0_withOffset.Offset.Hours);
```

Comment: Well, it *moves* the problem. You've expressed the question in terms of DST - but would you want two values which represent the same instant in time but on opposite sides of the world (e.g. one being 6am and one being 6pm) to compare as equal? We don't know what situation you're actually trying to model here, which makes it very hard to say whether this approach is appropriate.

Comment: Hello. I gladly appreciate you help. I agree it is not the same. It is code from unit test which just validates that adding day works well.